# Getting a specific category of data from firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I would like to categorize data in a Firebase realtime database and then select them by category to be  displayed in different sections of my android views but I don't know where to start. I am new to Firebase all I know is how to pull data, push to Firebase db  and display all the data fetched.

My question is: is this possible and if yes how can I go about it?
Thanks

Comment: If Realtime database is what you are talking about then Firebase has pretty good docs on how to work with Firebase. https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start/

Comment: I have gone through the docs but what I find is how to update specific data called children therein but what I want is how to read specific data or read whole and pull order them. I am asking for an equivalence of where in Sql

Comment: Firebase is conceptually different from SQL. What you get back is pretty much JSON format. So treat it like so. Write your own logic. Power of Firebase is easiness of set up and usage. If you need more table like with quick look up and all the relational algebra mambo jumbo use SQL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have this database:

```
Animals
   randomId
       name: dog
       category: mammal
   randomId
       name: snake
       category: reptile
   randomId
       name: elephants
       category: mammal
```

Then you can query by category:

```
DatabaseReference ref=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Animals");
Query query=ref.orderByChild("category").equalTo("mammal");

 query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
   @Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
  for(DataSnapshot datas: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
     String name=datas.child("name").getValue().toString();
    }
  }
   @Override
public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
     }
  });
```

This way you will retrieve all the names where category is equal to mammal.

Check here also:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data

Comment: Just exactly what I needed