# Trying to retrieve data from firebase where the category is equal to the string

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to retrieve data from the Firebase Realtime Database and I only want where the category is equal to a String. For example, if my string is football then I should get all the data that has the category football in it. I run my app with the code I am about to show you but I get nothing but a blank page. I don't know what I am doing wrong.

```
 databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    if (Categories.InternetConnection.checkConnection(Categories.this)) {

        databaseReference.child("Sports").orderByChild("category").equalTo("football")).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {


            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    myUploads.clear();

                for (DataSnapshot userSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    for (DataSnapshot postsnapshot : userSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        Model_Information upload = postsnapshot.getValue(Model_Information.class);
                     
                        Collections.shuffle(myUploads);
                      
                        myUploads.add(upload);
                        recyclerView.invalidate();
                    }
                }
                    linearLayoutWithoutItems.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    recyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    aAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Toast.makeText(Categories.this, databaseError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });
```

Firebase Json

```
{
  "MyStudents" : {
    "KihlyfLkJMQ5uZWBDgLWNuBHKAE2" : {
      "-MSr8HG6QCR2sO8MZHoM" : {
        "category" : "Football",
        "created" : "2-19-2021",
        "name" : "Benny",
        "time" : "2:47 AM",
        "timestamp" : 1613684875762
      },
      "-MSr8awtvzrmm3P6A2LB" : {
        "category" : "Basketball",
        "created" : "2-19-2021",
        "name" : "patrick",
        "time" : "2:49 AM",
        "timestamp" : 1613684960454,
      },
      "-MSr8mSn5OSTu5vdT4Wt" : {
        "category" : "Football",
        "created" : "2-19-2021",
        "name" : "Shawn",
        "time" : "2:50 AM",
        "timestamp" : 1613685007616,
      }

{
  "MyStudents" : {
    "WahlyfLkJMQ5uZWBDgLWNuBHKAE2" : {
      "-MSr8HG6QCR2sO8MZHoM" : {
        "category" : "Football",
        "created" : "2-19-2021",
        "name" : "Len",
        "time" : "2:47 AM",
        "timestamp" : 1613684875762
      },
      "JJr8awtvzrmm3P6A2LB" : {
        "category" : "Basketball",
        "created" : "2-19-2021",
        "name" : "Armstrong",
        "time" : "2:49 AM",
        "timestamp" : 1613684960454,
      },
      "-JJr8mSn5OSTu5vdT4Wt" : {
        "category" : "Football",
        "created" : "2-19-2021",
        "name" : "Bill",
        "time" : "2:50 AM",
        "timestamp" : 1613685007616,
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code lies in the fact that you are using an incorrect query:

```
databaseReference.child("Sports").orderByChild("category").equalTo("football"))
```

Assuming that `MyStudents` is a child right under your root node and the following statement:

```
if (Categories.InternetConnection.checkConnection(Categories.this)) { /* ... */ }
```

Returns `true`, please use the following query:

```
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference uidRef = rootRef.child(uid);
Query queryByCategory = uidRef.orderByChild("category").equalTo("Football");
queryByCategory.addValueEventListener(/* ... */);
```

Things to notice:

1. `KihlyfLkJMQ5uZWBDgLWNuBHKAE2` is the UID of the logged-in user and should be added as a child in the reference.
2. The value of the category property is called "Football" and **not** "football", with lower-case "f".

**Edit:**

According to your last comment:

> I'm not trying to just get their information I'm trying to get everyone that has students whose category is Football

There is no way you can achieve that using your actual database structure. The most simple solution I can think of is to create a new node that contains all `Model_Information` objects, no matter the user is. This practice is called denormalization and is a common practice when it comes to Firebase. For a better understanding, I recommend you see this video, [Denormalization is normal with the Firebase Database](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vKqXSZLLnHA).

Also, when you are duplicating data, there is one thing that needs to keep in mind. In the same way, you are adding data, you need to maintain it. In other words, if you want to update/delete an item, you need to do it in every place that it exists.

Comment: sir I don't need the current user id. I need all the data with the category Football.

Comment: The next node after the `MyStudents` node is `KihlyfLkJMQ5uZWBDgLWNuBHKAE2`. This seems like the UID of the logged-in user. This UID should also be added to your reference. So you definitely need it. Yes, the above code, is what you are looking for. It gets all the data where the `category` is Football. Have you even try it?

Comment: I edited my code for the json part. I am not trying get the Uid of the logged in user

Comment: Using the code from my answer, you are **not** getting the UID, you are simply using it in your reference. Because `WahlyfLkJMQ5uZWBDgLWNuBHKAE2` is present in the database, you need to add it to your reference. Have you tried my code?

Comment: Sir I understand but I'm not trying use the logged in users Uid as the reference because then it will only results that belongs to them. I'm not trying to just get their information I'm trying get everyone that  has students who category is Football not just logged in user. So I should get `KihlyfLkJMQ5uZWBDgLWNuBHKAE2` who has students in football and  `WahlyfLkJMQ5uZWBDgLWNuBHKAE2` who has students in football

Comment: In this case, please see my updated answer.

Comment: unfortunately your answer didn't help me. The link you sent did not help either. My question is simple I just want to retrieve all data that matches the category that is equal to Football

Comment: just like this [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51406414/getting-a-specific-category-of-data-from-firebase]

Comment: And as I already told you, you **cannot** achieve that using your actual structure. There is no **way** you can do that. The option that you have is to use denormalization and have all those objects within a single node, right?

Comment: But what about using filter?

Comment: There is no filter method for that. Have you tried to use denormalization? Does it work?

Comment: Ok sir. I'm going to look into the denormalization again.

Comment: Sir I found my answer. I did not need to use denormalization for this. Maybe I was not as clear but I will put my answer on here to show you what I was talking about. @Alex Mamo

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer. Hopefully its helpful for someone :)

```
    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("MyStudents");
        if (Categories.InternetConnection.checkConnection(Categories.this)) {
    
            databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    
    
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    
                        myUploads.clear();
    
                    for (DataSnapshot userSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        for (DataSnapshot postsnapshot : userSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                            Model_Information upload = postsnapshot.getValue(Model_Information.class);
                         
                            Collections.shuffle(myUploads);
    
                                    if (upload.getCategory().equals("Football")) {
                                        myUploads.add(upload);
                                    }else{
                                       
   Toast.makeText(Categories.this, "No results", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    
                                    }
    
                                    recyclerView.invalidate();
                                }
                          
                            myUploads.add(upload);
                            recyclerView.invalidate();
                        }
                    }
                        
    
                        aAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    
                }
    
                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    Toast.makeText(Categories.this, databaseError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    
                }
            });
```

Comment: This solution is definitely **not** an option. Downloading an entire object (node) to search for field values client-side isn't practical at all. Imagine you have 1 MIL children and only a single one has the category set to "Football". Are you willing to download all 1 MIL elements to search for a single one? That's a tremendous waste of bandwidth and resources. Using a Query, you'll always return only the elements you are interested in. So denormalization is the best option that you have in your use-case.